# error:Invalid start tag plist in Eclipse using the ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have configured an XML Catalog as follows:

```
Entry element:   Public
Location:    LindbergCorp.MyPrayers/PropertyList.dtd
URI: platform:/resource/LindbergCorp.MyPrayers/PropertyList.dtd
Key type:    Public ID
Key:     -//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
```

Following is an xml file in the res\values folder (located here because it will have entries in the values-?? folders too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "the http address is here too">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>1-1</key>
    <array>
        <string>Cross Style</string>
        <string>setCrossStyleCell::</string>
        <string>updateCrossStyle:</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

When i edit this XML file in eclipse, it give the "invalid start tag" message on the  line.

If i save the xml file, the marker goes away, until i clean the project.

Is there something additional i have to do with the ADT plugin to make it recognise XML files that use a different scheme?

Thanks -- Dan'l

Comment: I found the solution.  xml files in the res\values directory must have <resource> as the root element.  Other xml files need to be in the res\xml-<qualifier> directories.  It helps to read the docs :)

Comment: So exactly what is the name of the folder you put the plist file into?

Comment: raw.  Short and sweet answer.  I hope it helps.  Sorry, i should have updated my solution when i found the real answer.  The documentation indicates the use of res\xml-<qualifier>.  In this case i used res\raw-<qualifier> (i.e. res\raw or res\raw-de (for German).

Answer (score 0):

I think that xml files in the res\values directory must have  as the root element. Other xml files need to be in the res\xml- directories. ;-)